# Eclipse for JBoss EAP 5.1

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I have jboss EAP 5.1 .I want to know which eclipse works with this jboss version. Does eclipse 3.6 Helios work with Jboss EAP 5.1? Can struts 1.1 be run in jboss EAP 5.1?

Comment: "Works with" meaning that the Eclipse JBoss Tools work, or simply can you develop applications for a separate instance of JBoss EAP 5.1?

Comment: @Roy Truelove :- Works means whether the jboss EAP 5.1 can be intergrated (started/stopped ) through which version of eclipse.The latter question is correct.I want to migrate my java webapps from the jboss 4.0.3 to jboss EAP 5.1 and want to know which version of eclipse works good for running webapplication in jboss EAP 5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Indigo and it has entries for JBoss EAP 5.x in it's list of supported services.  It will run struts 1.1. as well.

Comment: I downloaded eclipse indigo  http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr2 .But this eclipse shows jboss 5.0 in server list like in ganymede 3.4. Will indigo work with jboss 5.1 EAP?

Comment: I used eclipse indigo and helios(eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32).Both work with struts 1.1 and jboss eap 5.1 .Thanks for the information.

Comment: The war file generated works on local windows  machine but gives out of memory on the jboss on linux box.what could be the reason for this?

Comment: It's probably out of memory :).  This should probably be the topic of a separate question, but make sure that the jboss instance has sufficient memory settings for your needs.

Comment: the same application war works on local machine but on the linux machine gives out of memory.the jvm memory is 512 Mb at both places.

Comment: I'd start another question with all of the details

Comment: https://community.jboss.org/thread/165423 this fixed issue. set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms128M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M" works !